# Reg Expression to ignore limited special characters javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Using Jquery validator plugin in my implementation. Need a regular expression which excludes special characters like , and &.

is there any regular expression for this. also if this special characters are anywhere in the string it should find and throw the error.

Comment: use this regex to check whether your input contain non-word chars or not `.*\W`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions like this:

```
[\,\&]
```

you can add as much as u want to this.

try it out yourself on this site:

http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
/[,&]/g
```

matches `,` and `&`.
Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gY0mC3/2#javascript

If you want to search for every special character except letters, numbers and the underscore, use

```
/\W/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gY0mC3/5#javascript

If you need to include spaces (e.g. a name) use

```
/[^\w\s]/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gY0mC3/4#javascript

Answer (score 0):

The brackets `[]` define custom regex classes.

To match a character for *only* those characters, you can do `[\,\&]`.

To match all *except* that, you can add a ^, such as `[^\,\&]`.

To match any non-word character, you can use `\W` (any character not a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _).

To include an underscore, you can do `[\W_]`.

Keep in mind that whitespaces are represented by `\s` and that depending on your environment, you may need to escape (add an additional backslash to) your backslashes.